# R - dmultinom if x occurs less than a certain amount of times

Tags: r

Say I know the probability of some data:

- A: 2%
- B: 55%
- C: 43%

In a sample of 30 randomly selected items containing A,B and C, I want to know the probability of say B occuring less than 5 times.

Currently I have:

```
dmultinom(x=c(0,5,0), prob = c(0.02, 0.55, 0.43))
```

How would I go about doing this in R? I can solve it on paper no problem, but not quite sure how to do it programatically. Not quite sure if I'm using the right function. Appreciate the help!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448641/confusion-over-dmultinom-function-arguments-and-meaning-with-respect-to-math

Answer (score 0):

Since the multinomial distribution is discrete, dmultinom is actually the probability mass function of the multinomial distribution. You can calculate the probability of specific configurations using `dmultinom`. Some examples:

```r
> dmultinom(x = c(10, 5, 15), size = 30, prob = c(0.02, 0.55, 0.43))
[1] 7.627047e-13
> dmultinom(x = c(20, 5, 5), size = 30, prob = c(0.02, 0.55, 0.43))
[1] 5.873928e-28
> dmultinom(x=c(2,25,3), size = 30, prob = c(0.02, 0.55, 0.43))
[1] 1.463409e-05
> dmultinom(x=c(3,17,10), size = 30, prob = c(0.02, 0.55, 0.43))
[1] 0.002283587
```